# New Magento Security Patch (SUPEE-6285) – Install Immediately

Tags: security, magento, ssh, magento-1.7

I am new in magneto. my store var 1.7.0.2  need to update security patch(UPEE-6285).

I read many link without with ssl or without ssl install. but can't go with any one because i can't get backup my project and i want to go for easy steps can any one tell me easy steps for update security patch in magneto. I don't know what is ssh and how it run. 
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Probably better asked in ServerFault or SuperUser, i'm not sure which.
this is not a programming question.

Comment: Probably been answered several times over in magento.stackexchange where these type questions belong. This is a Magento administration question being asked in a programming section.

Comment: sorry but I just wondered this is programmatically solution so i asked here and i am new in magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn how to install a patch check this link out: https://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf

**Easy way:**

First create a backup then use **Magento connect** and upgrade your store to the latest Magento version by **check for upgrades** button. The latest version contains this security patch (SUPEE 6285) and another features all together.

update:

Upgrade using Magento connect on **production server** is not recommended, because you have to check extensions compatibility.

Comment: I completely disagree with what you are calling the "Easy way"! Upgrading your version of Magento is unlikely to be easy and will require checks and fixes to any extensions or customisations you have, and then significant testing. Not something to be attempted lightly. A patch is much more limited and easier to apply to your current version.

Comment: Doing a full system upgrade across versions (1.7.x to 1.9.x) without checking for incompatibility with installed modules and themes is a good way to suffer economic disaster, if you do this on your live website. Especially if you don't back up your current database and web directory tree. And then there's always the beautiful partial install that Magento Connect is notorious for... Bad advice all round. Do it first on a development server for severe testing, or not at all. The reason for patches is to get the issue taken care of immediately without downing your website due to dud upgrade.

Comment: Doesn't everyone have dev test prod which they use for any update, including patching?! :o)

Comment: i am disappointed with the answer why anyone upgrade the whole version just for security patch. in short need clean way.